# Chatroom deleted?

Tags: support, chat

I created a chatroom about the Qt Framework some time ago but it seems it's no longer available. The [chatroom URL](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2203/qt-framework) just says "Page Not Found" and the possible reasons for removal are "spam, off topic, abuse" but I don't think any of this concerns the chatroom (though I was rarely checking it). Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 6):

From the [faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

That room has 7 messages, the latest one being 13 days old. Hence the room has been auto-deleted.

Comment: So another advantage to be 10k?

Comment: Rather unrelated, but it's probably worth putting the strike through `---` in the FAQ formatting section. Not worth a post all of its own, so I'm just mentioning it here since I remembered.

Comment: @Tim maybe, but I still consider that an experimental feature

Answer (score 1):

It's just deleted, because that room was inactive. Feel free to create new one

There are no offensive nor abusive posts.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, I just tried again and I still see the same "Page Not Found" message - http://tinypic.com/r/2qbgfwm/7

Comment: You have >10k rep, so you can see deleted rooms. @Laurent doesn't.

Comment: @balpha: yep, as I said in your posts. Thanks for response.